# What is the proper way to show AlertDialog when processing onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I am using a QR/barcode scanner library and one of the endpoints is `onActivityResult`.

Upon reading the result I get an invalid format (to my app) how can I prompt an `AlertDialog` properly. Currently, I am getting

> Activity com.binscanner.*.scanner.QrScan has leaked window
>   DecorView@48dd8f3[Trouble connecting to server] that was originally
>   added here

Here is a snippet of how I am using the Dialog.

```
    private AlertDialog showSimpleAlertDialog(String title, String message, final DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QrScan.this).create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", okListener);

//      alertDialog.show();
        return alertDialog;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        showSimpleAlertDialog("Trouble connecting to server", "Going back main menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             // Go to some other view
            }
        }).show();

    }
```

I am unsure how to get this flow work as intended.

An Intent starts by the library to start the scanner. When I scan the barcode/qrcode I do `onActivityResult`. I want an AlertDialog to show up, but in  the process, activities are somehow different. How can I get them properly synced up?

Comment: u need pop up dialog after the scan complete to show the result ??

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow quitiing `QRScan` `Activity` before showing `dialog`. The cause of quiting of that `Activity` might be an **unhandled** `Exception` that causes `Activity` to Shutdown.

Call `dismiss()` on the `Dialog` instance you created in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

One probable cause for this behavior would be un-handled orientation change. When you try to access camera for QR code, your orientation might be changed based on the capture method. This would cause your current activity to be killed and restarted.

Try to handle the orientation configuration changes by yourself. Tutorial to do so can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: The orientation is definitely changing. If I wanted to trigger a dialog, would I have to set a flag for it and when I use the orientation hook use the bool to show the dialog? Is that how it is usually done? It feels weird doing it like this but idk of any other way.

Comment: If you handle the orientation change by yourself, then you dont have to maintain a flag. But if you want to rely on system then you have to create a flag. Dismiss tge dialog in `onStop` and set the flag. In `onStart` check if flag is set, if so, show the dialog again.